# Python OpenCV parallel use with joblib or multiprocessing Pool

Tags: python, opencv, parallel-processing, threadpool, joblib

I am attempting to compute homographies for pairs of images in parallel with Python 3 and [joblib](http://academic.bancey.com/parallelization-in-python-example-with-joblib/). We have bounding boxes for objects in the left image and want to find the corresponding bounding box in the right image. However, using the approach shown below, only one of my machines cores appears to be utilised.

```
#THIS CORRESPONDS TO ONE LOOP ITERATION.
def processOneImage(params):
    #Unpack params
    leftFname, leftImgDir, rightImgDir, leftDetectionDir, rightDetectionDir = params

    #Load detections. Early out if none.
    objectDetections = []
    detFname = leftDetectionDir + leftFname[:-4] + '.txt'
    with open(detFname, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            objectDetections.append(line.split())
        f.close()
    if len(objectDetections) == 0:
        return None

    #Load images.
    leftImg = cv2.imread(leftImgDir + leftFname)
    rightImg = cv2.imread(rightImgDir + leftFname)

    #Compute homography.
    H = computeHomography(leftImg, rightImg)
    if H is None:
        return None

    #Compute Bounding boxes and write out.
    outFname = rightDetectionDir + leftFname[:-4] + '.txt'
    outFile = open(outFname, 'w')
    processLabelBoundingBoxes(leftImg, rightImg, H, objectDetections, outFile)
    outFile.flush()
    outFile.close()

#HERE WE RUN THE "LOOP" IN PARALLEL
def processDataset(leftImgFnames, leftImgDir, rightImgDir, leftDetectionDir, rightDetectionDir):
    numItems = len(leftImgFnames)
    params = zip(leftImgFnames, [leftImgDir]*numItems, [rightImgDir]*numItems, [leftDetectionDir]*numItems, [rightDetectionDir]*numItems)
    res = joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=4, backend="multiprocessing")(map(joblib.delayed(processOneImage), params))
```

Is it possible to use OpenCV in this parallel fashion? If so, do I have to somehow specify to OpenCV which thread to run on?

EDIT: I have also tried with Pools from the python multiprocessing library as follows, however the result is the same.

```
def processDataset(leftImgFnames, leftImgDir, rightImgDir, leftDetectionDir, rightDetectionDir):
    numItems = len(leftImgFnames)
    params = zip(leftImgFnames, [leftImgDir]*numItems, [rightImgDir]*numItems, [leftDetectionDir]*numItems, [rightDetectionDir]*numItems)
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(4)#I have 4 cores/threads.
    p.map(processOneImage, params)
```

For completeness, here are the helper functions

```
#THIS USES OPENCV
def computeHomography(leftImg, rightImg):
    #Compute ORB keypoints and descriptors for both images.
    orb = cv2.ORB_create()
    keypointsLeft, descriptorsLeft = orb.detectAndCompute(leftImg, None)
    keypointsRight, descriptorsRight = orb.detectAndCompute(rightImg, None)

    bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
    matches = bf.match(descriptorsLeft, descriptorsRight)

    #Verify match quality.
    goodMatches = []
    for m in matches:
        goodMatches.append(m)

    if len(goodMatches) > 10:
        src_pts = np.float32([keypointsLeft[m.queryIdx].pt for m in goodMatches]).reshape(-1,1,2)
        dst_pts = np.float32([keypointsRight[m.trainIdx].pt for m in goodMatches]).reshape(-1,1,2)

        M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)
        return M
    return None

#THIS USES OPENCV    
def processLabelBoundingBoxes(leftImg, rightImg, H, objectDetections, outFile):
    instanceCounts = dict()
    for detection in objectDetections:
        objID = detection[0]
        objConf = float(detection[5])

        bb_x = int(detection[1])
        bb_y = int(detection[2])
        bb_w = int(detection[3]) - int(detection[1])
        bb_h = int(detection[4]) - int(detection[2])
        rect = (bb_x, bb_y, bb_w, bb_h)
        maskLeft = np.zeros(leftImg.shape[:2], np.uint8)

        #Replace this with the code below for graphcuts. This is bounding box.
        for x in range(bb_x, bb_x + bb_w):
            for y in range(bb_y, bb_y + bb_h):
                if x >= 0 and x < leftImg.shape[1] and y >= 0 and y < leftImg.shape[0]:
                    maskLeft[y][x] = 255

        maskRight = cv2.warpPerspective(maskLeft, H, (leftImg.shape[1], leftImg.shape[0]))

        #TO-DO: Find a way to do this automatically, with cv2 maybe...
        #Currently too lazy, it's late...
        xmin = rightImg.shape[1]
        xmax = 0
        ymin = rightImg.shape[0]
        ymax = 0
        for y in range(0, rightImg.shape[0]):
            for x in range(0, rightImg.shape[1]):
                if maskRight[y][x] > 0:
                    if y < ymin:
                        ymin = y
                    if y > ymax:
                        ymax = y
                    if x < xmin:
                        xmin = x
                    if x > xmax:
                        xmax = x
        bbox_width = xmax - xmin
        bbox_height = ymax - ymin

        outFile.write("%s %d %d %d %d %f\n" % (objID, xmin, ymin, bbox_width, bbox_height, objConf))
```